# can i pass php file into geoXml parser

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, google-maps-markers

i am having problems while fetching data from kml file.

```
geoXml.parse("http://localhost/maps/phpmysqlajax_genkml.kml");
```

error in console is

```
Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage    [Break On This Error] (92 out of range 43)
```

and what if i send a php file instead

```
geoXml.parse("http://localhost/maps/phpmysqlajax_genkml.php");
```

this file sending KML as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geoXml and KmlOverlay (in version 3 of the API) both require a KML file or GeoRSS file to be hosted on a server that is available to Google's servers to go and parse. localhost isn't. This is because you're not sending the KML to Google's servers, but rather telling them to fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you totally sure phpmysqlajax_genkml.kml is valid KML file? We can't tell.

> what if i send a php file instead

What is the problem you are getting? It should work.